# Mysql query - where clause with result of subquery

Tags: mysql

i am totally depressed with this query, which i am solving for many hours :(

```
SELECT m_order.id,       
 (SELECT SUM(price*amount) FROM m_order_item as item WHERE item.id_order = m_order.id) AS total
FROM `m_order` 
WHERE total > 100
```

It returns **Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'** constantly, but in result without this problematic where clause column with name "total" is totally ok and calculated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). Put it into a `HAVING` instead:

```
SELECT m_order.id,       
 (SELECT SUM(price*amount) FROM m_order_item as item WHERE item.id_order = m_order.id) AS total
FROM `m_order` 
HAVING total > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Total is a column alias  and is not visible for where condition  .. where part is evaluated  by bd engine before the evaluation of select clause

so you should or repeat the code

```
SELECT m_order.id,       
 (  SELECT SUM(price*amount) 
    FROM m_order_item as item 
    WHERE item.id_order = m_order.id ) AS total
FROM `m_order` 
WHERE  (  SELECT SUM(price*amount) 
    FROM m_order_item as item 
    WHERE item.id_order = m_order.id ) > 100
```

or try using having 
having filter the result of select

```
  SELECT m_order.id,       
   (  SELECT SUM(price*amount) 
      FROM m_order_item as item 
      WHERE item.id_order = m_order.id ) AS total
  FROM `m_order` 
  HAVING  total >  100
```